# Not getting signal from Flask-Security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I want to receive the user_registered signal from Flask-Security and have to set up like so:

```
from flask.ext.security.signals import user_registered

@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def user_registered_sighandler(sender, **extra):
    sender.logger.debug("logger-user_registered_sighandler:", extra)
    print "print-user_registered_sighandler:", extra
```

But my signal handler is not being called when a new user is registered.  I've set up a Flask (not Flask-Security) signal similar to above that does work. Can anyone help with this?

I'm using: Flask==0.9, Flask-Security==1.5.4, blinker==1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug fixed](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/commit/f1cca43d9cef9ea616c1a51e862f91ad49bb9fca) in v1.6.1 of Flask-Security