# Difference between python 2.7 and 3.3+ when importing in __init__.py and module from same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import, flask-security

Recently I had an issue where a [signal I was using from flask-security was not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945330/flask-security-user-registered-signal-not-received-in-python-3-3-but-works-in-2) in python 3.3.  In looking at the source code for flask-security I noticed that the signal I was importing from a module in the flask-security package was also imported in `__init__.py`.  By importing the signal from the top level of the package I was able to solve my problem (since the signal gets imported when package is initialized).

If I run the following code:

```
from flask.ext.security import user_registered
from flask.ext.security.signals import user_registered as user_reg_sig
user_registered==user_reg_sig
```

I'll get `True` in python 2.7 and I'll get `False` for python 3.3+.

What is different in python 3.3+ that causes this difference in import behaviour?

**EDIT:**
I'm still stumped by the python 2.7 vs 3.3+ issue, but have managed to narrow down that the issue is occurring when the [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/ext/__init__.py) of flask.ext is called and uses the ExtensionImporter class from [exthook.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/exthook.py) to import flask-security.

Running the following under python 3.4 returns `True` when flask-security is directly imported avoiding the extension hook:

```
from flask_security.signals import user_registered as user_reg_sig
from flask_security import user_registered
user_registered==user_reg_sig
```

Here is repr() for signals for flask.ext.security and flask_security examples:

```
from flask_security.signals import user_registered as user_reg_sig
from flask_security import user_registered

repr(user_registered)
>>> "<blinker.base.NamedSignal object at 0x7fb38e258400; 'user-registered'>"

repr(user_reg_sig)
>>> "<blinker.base.NamedSignal object at 0x7fb38e258400; 'user-registered'>"

from flask.ext.security import user_registered
from flask.ext.security.signals import user_registered as user_reg_sig

repr(user_registered)
>>> "<blinker.base.NamedSignal object at 0x7fb38e258400; 'user-registered'>"

repr(user_reg_sig)
>>> "<blinker.base.NamedSignal object at 0x7fb38dd030b8; 'user-registered'>"
```

Comment: And if you print out the repr of each?

Comment: Added the repr within the question.  So definitely a different object when accessed through flask.ext.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798589/what-could-cause-a-python-module-to-be-imported-twice] and the changes in Python3.3 in that area. Also read this [http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple cases where Python can decide to create a new instance of an object when you re-import the module.

In fact that's not even Python 3 specific and it can happen in various scenarios.

Mainly you have to assume that the two objects may be different and work around this.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like there is a bit of an issue with the use of signals by Flask and what happens when imports happen through flask.ext.*